# @csrf_protect in django services

Tags: django, csrf-protection

I'm trying to use `@csrf_protect` in my services by following [Cross Site Request Forgery protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/)  article but it is not working for me.

This is my `settings` file

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',

]
```

and this is how I'm Acquiring the token

```
var csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');
```

And this is how I'm configuring the $http provider with the cookie and header names:

> $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
>
> $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';

But when I call any service, it returns `403 forbidden` error. Any Idea what I'm missing or doing wrong?

Any kind of help will be appreciated.